# Binding property inside nested class in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, class, nested, bind

Is it possible to bind property of the nested class in Silverlight?
I have code that looks like this:

```
public class A {
    public class B {
        public String Prop1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to assign a key for class B in xaml but I don't know how to do it. I tried something like this,

```
<controls:ChildWindow.Resources>
    <local:A:B x:Key="myProperty">
</controls:ChildWindow.Resources>
```

but it doesn't work.
Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753379.aspx):

> - Your custom class must be public and
>     support a default (parameterless)
>     public constructor. (See following
>     section for notes regarding
>     structures.)
> - **Your custom class must not be a nested class.** Nested classes
>     and the "dot" in their general CLR
>     usage syntax interfere with other WPF
>     and/or XAML features such as attached
>     properties.